# Cakephp: How would I route all missing controller/action calls to a single, general error page?

Tags: php, cakephp

I've got a cakephp app that I'm trying to get to serve up the `Pages::404` function (and corresponding view) whenever Cake encounters any error (missing controller, action, etc).

What's the best way to do that?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Cake automatically throws a 404 error for missing methods or controllers. While in debug mode, this error takes the form of a detailed error message containing instructions, like:

> Missing Controller
>
> Error: FooController could not be found.
>
> Error: Create the class FooController below in file: > app/controllers/foo_controller.php
>
> Notice: If you want to customize this error message, create app/views/errors/missing_controller.ctp

In production mode (`debug = 0`) the message just looks like this:

> Not Found
>
> Error: The requested address '/foo' was not found on this server.

These error pages are defined in `cake/libs/view/errors/`. As the message in debug mode says, you can create your own, custom error pages (using the same name as the ones in the `cake/` directory) in `app/views/errors/`.

If you want to execute a custom function on errors, you'll best put it in the `AppError` Controller as described in [Error Handling](http://book.cakephp.org/view/154/Error-Handling).

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to have a single 404 page rather than a pages/404, and many different error pages for missing models, controllers, actions, views, etc...

Comment: Create your custom 404 page in `app/views/errors/error404.ctp` and you're done. As said above, in debug mode you'll receive more detailed errors, while in production mode every 'Missing X' error will be displayed as 404 error using `error404.ctp`.

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't realize that error404.ctp would handle *all* errors.

Comment: Cool! If I could handle 503 error like this way, please?

Answer (score 10):

Step 1:In app_controller.php add two functions

```
function _setErrorLayout() {  
     if ($this->name == 'CakeError') {  
        $this->layout = 'error';  
     }    
}              

function beforeRender () {  
      $this->_setErrorLayout();
    }
}
```

Step2: In `views\layouts\`   create `error.ctp`
containing  echo $content_for_layout;

step:3 In `views\errors\` 
make `missing_action.ctp` and customize the page as you need
my PHP code was:

```
 echo $html->image('404-not-found-1-3.jpg');
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you in the controller when you are trying to redirect to the 404 error page?

Well if that is the case, you can walk around the problem like this:

Copy and paste the error layout (error404.ctp) from the cake
core library directory into yours app/views/errors/

Then add the following line whenever you encounter an error inside a controller.

```
$this->cakeError('error404',array(array('url'=>'/')));
```

Oh, another way to handle this is to edit the routes.php file in app/config

[CakePHP Official site Routes-Configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/view/46/Routes-Configuration)

I don't have a working copy of CakePHP at the moment, so I would just describe the basic logic here(what you can do inside the routes.php file)

Redirect traffic with specific url patterns(say, http://yourwebsite/validController/validFunction/validParam) to their corresponding destinations respectively.
Redirect all other traffic (missing controller, model, view, etc) to 404 page.

Hope that helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Please add a class PostController.php not post_controller.php in the app/controller folder. It just mean that You have to create as like its class name.

Comment: When this question was created (in 2009!) the standard was lowercase + underscores.