# Is it possible in Cakephp it intercept a no action found event and handle it in the controller?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I would like to handle a missing action in one of my controllers in a default action. Now the default behavior is to throw an error. I would like to be able to have a default action in that controller that is called and passed the name of the action requested so I may do something with it. Now I know you can change the whole missing action page which is not what I am looking to do. Any incite on this would be great, if its not possible please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745968/cakephp-how-would-i-route-all-missing-controller-action-calls-to-a-single-gener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on how much of an exception to your normal actions this is, a change in routing may make more sense:

```
Router::connect('/mycontroller/*',
                array('controller' => 'mycontroller', 'action' => 'catchall'));
```

If you have *some* normal actions in that controller, define a route for them before this catch-all route to have them handled normally.

If you really want to futz around with the action handling in the controller itself, you should be able to do so in `beforeFilter`:

```
public function beforeFilter() {
    if (!method_exists($this, $this->action)) {
        unshift($this->params['pass'], $this->action);
        $this->action = 'catchall';
    }
}
```

Something like that at least, that's just a quick untested idea.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. I had to prevent the default HTML error page for a JSON-responding controller.

The way @deceze suggested didn't work for me for some different reasons:

1. After routing with the wildcard to a specific action, the invoked action is always the one you defined in `routes.php`. BUT the action from the URI is passed as the first argument.
2. You cannot overwrite `$this->action`, but you can use `$this->setAction()`

What I did:

1. Route all calls to a specific action

   ```
   Router::connect('/ajax/*', array('controller' => 'ajax', 'action' => 'handle'));
   ```
2. Parse the call in this action

   ```
   public function beforeFilter() {
       $this->autoRender = false;
   }

   public function index($arg1 = false) {
       return new CakeResponse(array('body' => json_encode(array('foo' => $arg1))));
   }

   public function handle($action = '') {
       if (method_exists($this, $action)) {
           return call_user_func_array(array($this,'setAction'),  func_get_args());
       } else {
           return $this->_error();
       }
   }

   private function _error() {
       return new CakeResponse(array('body' => json_encode(array('status' => 'error'))));
   }
   ```

Hope this will helpful for someone.